# Selenium - Automate Chrome Browser Extension - Lighthouse

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, lighthouse

I am trying to integrate Lighthouse in my Selenium scripts

Basically each time my script lands on new page I should click on the Lighthouse extension and generate a report.

What I could Achieve: (sample working code at the end)
Setting up desired capabilities to launch Chrome with Lighthouse extension added

What I am unable to do:
I want to use the added

1. While on the desired web page
2. Click on Chrome Extension button and select Lighthouse extension
3. In the Lighthouse extension pop up displayed Click on "Generate Report" button

Sample working code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\v744536\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();
        opt.addExtensions(new File("C:\\Users\\v744536\\eclipse-workspace\\AccessibilityProject\\LH.crx")); 
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities ();
        capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, opt);
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I should tell you that the Lighthouse browser extension simply calls the PSI API, which is free and easy to use directly: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/get-started

The extension directs you to a page, and that page will use the PSI API. If you don't want to use the PSI API directly, another option is to just open the Lighthouse Viewer with the url you want:

https://googlechrome.github.io/lighthouse/viewer/?psiurl=https://www.example.com

That's all the extension is doing under the hood. This would be much simpler than via scripting user interactions.

Source: I work on Lighthouse.

Comment: What if the page is running on localhost?

Comment: Then you'll have to use DevTools.

Comment: how do we do a lighthouse if the page is protected? so we need to login to the site first. but passing the URL of the page as a query string will not work. do you have any suggestion how to do a lighthouse test on a protected page

Comment: I'll link you to our docs on the subject: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/main/docs/authenticated-pages.md

Comment: Not mentioned (needs to be updated ) is to use the new user flows feature and script the login process.